# Style button in upload type

Tags: css

I have a style that I apply to my buttons. Can I apply the same style to the button of the file upload element without affecting the entry field?

```
<input type="file" name="myFile">
```

Answer (score 6):

The designing of file element is not supported by almost all browser. Some browser allow it and some browser does not allow it.

You can not make it browser compatible. Basically you do not have complete control to design it.

You can also go with this [article](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html)

Comment: @ santa : be careful with this technics, because you will have accessibility problems

Answer (score 2):

Due to security concerns, browsers doesn't allow you to edit or style the upload button. It can be exploited to trick the user. [Example](https://bug57770.bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=17860)